# Colorize a branch of a given name when using git log

Tags: git

I would like to have my `git log` output colorized so that certain branch names appear on a given color.

For example, I would like `master` branch name to be displayed in purple, and `my-other-branch` to be displayed in blue. I would also like to specify for instance `origin/another-branch` in orange.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this in git, and if yes, how?

Comment: Not possible. See the color configuration for [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorbranchltslotgt) and [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-colordecorateltslotgt) in `git help config`

Comment: As mentioned above, not possible out of box. A sort of possible way of doing so is creating your `git log --format=...` marking ref names somehow (say, adding special characters prepending and appending the `%d` placeholder to parse easier) and colorizing such output using, say, `sed` or a more complex script. Not sure if it's worth implementing it like that since it requires special output from `git log`. And one more solution is renaming your local master branch to`master` keeping the upstream branch to the remote `master` -- believe me it's visible enough.

Comment: @fluffy That could be an answer.